# Android: Visible viewpager tab contains arraylist data of previous tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager with two tabs in my app (A and B). The first tab i.e A has a listview. Clicking on any of the items in the list opens a new fragment (let's call it C) with another list. The tab B also has a listview.

The list in tab B and the list contained in the fragment C have the same type of items. That is each item of both list is of the same class. I have used a recycler view with a custom adapter to create the list. Since both lists in tab B and fragment c are of the same object type I have used the same adapter, namely (CarListAdapter.class) for this purpose.

The problem I am facing is that when I open fragment C then go back to tab A and then right swipe  so that tab B is visible, clicking on an item in tab B causes null pointer exception, reason being that the list in fragment CarListFragment.class still has the data from fragment C and not tab B.(However the list is rendered properly, it is only the click that is not working properly)

Since two instance of this adapter are present I expected this to work fine. If however I use two different adapters with exact same code like (CarListAdapterC.class and CarListAdapterB.class) the code works fine.

I am stuck, can someone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it was really stupid on my part. I had **static** fields in RecyclerView Adapter. Removing them worked like a charm.

Comment: I don't have any static fields and it doesn't work again.can you tell me which version of support library do you use?and can you provide me with your adapter code and How you use it?

Comment: 23.0.1, you can create a question with your code if you want !! There must be some problem, I'll post the code there if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered same problem when using view pager and **recycler view**. I have searched allot and as i know it's an issue in **recycler view adapte**r.

As you may know **view pager** load one more next page by default every time it shows a page.and here is where adapter shows the problem.The different instances of a same adapter that you create point to same place.because of that it still has other pages items.

I know it's not a good idea but i have created another adapter same as the first one with different name and used it for the next list and it worked.try to separate your list's adapters.let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes you are right, that is precisely what I said, if I create another adapter it does work. Sorry I wrote fragments in the question, if I create CarListAdapterB and CarListAdapterC it does work. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Hey I found my problem, have a look at my answer, I guess you must be having the same problem. :)